# How to prove that $A \in B(\ell^1 , \ell^2 )$ and compute $\|A\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Consider the Banach spaces
$\ell^1 = \{x = (x_1, x_2,\dots) : \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i| < \infty, x_i \in C \text{ for all } i\}$,
$\ell^2 = \{x = (x_1, x_2,\dots) : \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^2 < \infty, x_i \in C \text{ for all } I\}$,
which are equipped with the norms $\|x\|_1 = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|$ and $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|x_i|^2}$, respectively.
For each $x \in \ell^1$ define
$$A(x) = (x_1,1/2(x_1 + x_2),1/4(x_1 + x_2 + x_3),1/8(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4),\dots)$$
Prove that $A \in B(\ell^1,\ell^2)$ and compute |A|.

I have try using Jensen inequality to prove that $A \in B(\ell^1,\ell^2)$, but I have not reached any conclusions

Comment: For any $x=(x_n) \in \ell^1$, write down $\|Ax\|_2^2$. From this you should be able to see $A$ is bounded by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, and also get a smell of $\|A\|$.

Comment: Please learn the basics of MathJax so that this can be read. As it stands, it's hopeless. And, rather than just typing your homework, please include more of your own actual efforts. Saying "I have not reached any conclusions" is not showing good effort.

Comment: I've changed your post to include MathJax. It's pretty similar to the LaTeX you were using, but needed more dollar signs. I also corrected the definition of the 2-norm. Please make sure I didn't introduce any errors. I do agree that you should say more about your Jensen attempt

Answer (score 0):

By definition, showing that $A$ is a bounded operator from $\ell^1$ to $\ell^2$ consists of finding a positive constant $C > 0$ such that the following holds:
$$ \| A(x) \|_{\ell^2} \le C\|x\|_{\ell^1}, \quad \forall x \in \ell^1. $$

Now, unravel the definition of $A$ to find that, for $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots) \in \ell^1$,
\begin{align} 
    \| A(x) \|^2_{\ell^2} &= x_1^2 + \frac{1}{4}(x_1 + x_2)^2 + \frac{1}{16}(x_1 + x_2 + x_3)^2 + \cdots \\
    &\le (1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots)(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots)^2 \\
    &= (1 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{16} + \cdots)\|x\|^2_{\ell^1}.
\end{align}

The conclusion follows by taking the square root on both sides (as $1 + 1/4 + 1/16 + \cdots < +\infty$).

Regarding the norm of the operator $A,$ by definition
$$ \| A \|_{B(\ell^1, \ell^2)} = \sup_{\| x \|_{\ell^1} \le 1} \| A(x) \|_{\ell^2}.$$ Now try to play around with various $x$. Bear in mind that for $x$ to be in $\ell^1$, this means that somehow the tail of the sequence has to decrease as a certain rate. Compare this rate of decay with the decay of $(1, 1/2, 1/4, \cdots)$ to understand which terms will contribute the most in the norm, and ultimately find the $x$ achieving this supremum.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your help has been really useful.

Comment: @Oihane please then consider validating my answer (with the up arrow)