# How to prove that $A \in B(\ell^1,\ell^2)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I have a similar question as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4355251) one, but in my case,
$$A(x)=\left(x_1,x_2+\frac{x_1}2,x_3+\frac{x_2}2+\frac{x_1}4,x_4+\frac{x_3}2+\frac{x_2}4+\frac{x_1}8,\dots\right)$$
I tried first bounding it in an arithmetical way, but I didn't reach any conclusion, because of the coefficients $\frac 12,\frac 14,...$ Then I saw this publication and I tried to do it with the suggestions you put, but I can not use the inequality that is used here, again because of the coefficients $\frac 12,\frac 14,...$ and then I tried using Jensen, but as I haven't worked before with this inequality, I don't know if I am using it in the correct way. I took an $x\in \ell^1$ which norm is equal to $1$ and interprete A as an infinite matrix with coefficients $a_{ij}$ and so $Ax=(\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{1j}x_j, \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{2j}x_j,
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{3j}x_j,...)$. Then I applied Jensen:

Suppose $1\le p<\infty$, $0\le y_1,y_2,\dots<C$ for some finite constant C.
Further assume that $b_1,b_2,\dots$ are nonnegative reals such that their
sum is $1$.  Then

$(\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i y_i)^p \le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} b_i y_i^p$

But at the end, I got the square root of the norm of $x$.

Comment: This operator is bounded from $\ell^2$ to $\ell^2.$ Therefore it is also bounded from $\ell^1$ to $\ell^2.$ Do you need a detailed solution ? It is based on the Schur test.